# Tuning SVC Classifier From Numpy Array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, classification, svm

first post here.

I'm pretty new to machine learning and am currently getting to grips with SVMs.

I currently have a set of data in a Numpy array and I am struggling to get any decent sort of accuracy. I understand that there is a way to tune the parameters of an SVM to make it more accurate for the data which I have.

A sample of the data I have is shown below:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   Class
    62  0   1   12  231 0   5   7   0   1   0
    17  0   2   412 754 1   4   8   1   2   0
    54  1   0   104 100 0   4   2   1   2   1
    18  0   2   189 172 1   2   8   0   2   1
    41  1   0   311 612 1   1   3   0   1   0
```

This is just a sample, I have over 7000 records.

I currently have the data in (apart from class) in a Numpy array named X, and the class data in a Numpy array named y.

I've tried feature selection but the highest accuracy i'm getting is 85% and I'd like to know how to be able to tune the parameters of the SVC to make it more accurate for my data.

Any help here would be a big help.

Thanks in advance, Isaac.

Comment: You might want to have a look at `GridSearchCV`

Comment: Example in the dupe. Classifier may be different, but the concept is the same.